# función mail() en PHP no envía correo Usando MAMP

Tags: php

No consigo hacer que se envíe un mensaje en modo local por medio de PHP. La configuración de php.ni me indica que está aparentemente ok hasta donde yo sé:

```
SMTP        localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25          25
```

Y el ejemplo simple en PHP para ver que va es:

```
<?php
$mail="nombre@dominio.net";
mail($email,
     "Activación de la cuenta",
     "Gracias por registrarse en nuestro sitio.
     Su cuenta ha sido creada, y debe ser activada antes de poder ser utilizada.
     Para activar la cuenta, haga click en el siguiente enlace o copielo en la
     barra de direcciones del navegador:
     http://activate.php?activation=");
?>
```

Comment: Trata de configurar Mercury en tu xampp puede que te funcione

Comment: ¿y tienes instalado y configurado el servidor de correo?

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: debes tener instaado un servidor de correo como sendmail si no quieres meterte en eso usa phpMailer.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Estoy usando Mac OSX.